# Bootstrap: How to make an image float-right with text wrapping AND responsiveness?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, formatting

I'm using Bootstrap right now and designing a web page that features an article with multiple images. The ones that float left work perfectly fine.

For the image to float on the right, I have tried:

1. Assigning the image the float-right class (simply doesn't work with no explanation)
2. Giving the text around the image a separate column (text does not wrap around image at bottom)
3. Assigning the order-1 and order-12 classes to their respective elements (fails without explanation) ("respective elements" meaning the first col div and the

   tag afterwards containing the text)

[image: a quick drawing of what i'm looking for]

And this is what my code looks like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <img src="resources/pic.jpg" width="100%" />
    <p>
      caption for photo here
    </p>
  </div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion CSS `shape-outside` is perfect for this kinda layout, unfortunately, it's not 100% ready yet, but we can try another way.

`float: left;` OR `float: right;` whatever you use for the image-holder element or the image itself, always put the image or image holder **BEFORE** the text (or the text-holder element).

Now, you **HAVE TO** use the `float` (`left` or `right`) **ONLY** in the image or image-holder, **NOT** in the text or text-holder. See the snippet below for a better understanding-

```css
img {max-width: 100%}

.the_article {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

.img-right {
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 15px 0;
}

.img-left {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="the_article">
    <figure class="img-right">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2693529/pexels-photo-2693529.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="">
    </figure>
    <section>
        <h2 style="text-align: right;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
        <p style="text-align: right;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim a nihil velit exercitationem adipisci hic? Praesentium quisquam odit earum eaque deserunt saepe repellat fugiat consequatur sint eveniet perspiciatis libero dolorem numquam commodi, rerum corporis, facere, similique consectetur itaque error! Eveniet qui ab odit ipsam! Magnam excepturi saepe quasi alias recusandae aliquid numquam odio nihil, natus reprehenderit deleniti. Accusamus maxime eum nihil ipsa dolorem? Modi, nihil! Rerum maxime fugiat, nemo doloremque sunt illum iusto molestiae, incidunt ad nulla quos dignissimos iure modi veritatis deserunt nisi. Dolorum fuga deserunt voluptates nisi officia consectetur et asperiores quam minus nulla odit veniam laborum repudiandae culpa, impedit, perferendis totam voluptate tenetur esse quo libero exercitationem consequatur reprehenderit quae. Eum in exercitationem odio et. Nam facere eos necessitatibus ad, nisi cum quidem, in maxime inventore nulla soluta ipsa assumenda reprehenderit, veritatis modi dolorem laborum. Fugiat sequi labore eligendi consequuntur perspiciatis accusamus? Tempora obcaecati inventore similique sed.</p>
    </section>
    <figure class="img-left">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2693529/pexels-photo-2693529.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="">
    </figure>
    <section>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim a nihil velit exercitationem adipisci hic? Praesentium quisquam odit earum eaque deserunt saepe repellat fugiat consequatur sint eveniet perspiciatis libero dolorem numquam commodi, rerum corporis, facere, similique consectetur itaque error! Eveniet qui ab odit ipsam! Magnam excepturi saepe quasi alias recusandae aliquid numquam odio nihil, natus reprehenderit deleniti. Accusamus maxime eum nihil ipsa dolorem? Modi, nihil! Rerum maxime fugiat, nemo doloremque sunt illum iusto molestiae, incidunt ad nulla quos dignissimos iure modi veritatis deserunt nisi. Dolorum fuga deserunt voluptates nisi officia consectetur et asperiores quam minus nulla odit veniam laborum repudiandae culpa, impedit, perferendis totam voluptate tenetur esse quo libero exercitationem consequatur reprehenderit quae. Eum in exercitationem odio et. Nam facere eos necessitatibus ad, nisi cum quidem, in maxime inventore nulla soluta ipsa assumenda reprehenderit, veritatis modi dolorem laborum. Fugiat sequi labore eligendi consequuntur perspiciatis accusamus? Tempora obcaecati inventore similique sed.</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for me, as I want the width of the image to be responsive.